# Looking for a library routine which can take diff's output and produce an HTML display of the differences?

Tags: html, web-browser, display, diff

I need some procedure in any commonly used language, that can produce the difference between two files and produce the HTML to display them side by side or in an interleaved manner.

I need to compare small files quickly and easily in my own application which uses an embedded browser control, so the language itself does not matter. So long as the procedure can run the `diff` process itself or can take the output of the `diff` command it will be okay.

The images below are those from the [Redmine](http://www.redmine.org) diff screen.

[image: Inline Diff]

[image: Side by Side]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple unified-diff htmliser is [diff2html](http://wiki.droids-corp.org/articles/d/i/f/Diff2html.html). It is written in python.